# Auth failure with Volley request (SPNEGO)

Tags: android, android-volley, spnego

I'm trying to cosume a soap service. If I consume any webservice that not is needed any auth, work perfectly, but I have a problem when auth is nedded.

I use the next code, but receive this message:

> com.android.volley.AuthFailureError

```
 // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            String url ="http://XXXX";

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                            mTextView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    mTextView.setText("That didn't work!"+error);
                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    try {
                        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        String key = "Authorization";
                        String encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(String.format("%s:%s", "USERNAME", "Password").getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
                        String value = String.format("Basic %s", encodedString);
                        map.put(key, value);
                        return map;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("ERROR", "Authentication Filure" );
                    }
                    return super.getParams();
                }
            };
    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
            queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Logicaly I use other server, user, and pass..

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I try to use postman chrome extension for connecting to webservice, and have the same problem. After investigating, I found that microsoft use other type of authentification with webservices named SPNEGO.

I don't found info for use SPNEGOin header authentification.. Any idea??